# Plotting values after the ninth decimal point

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to make a plot using `pgfplots` of a variable that only changes after the ninth decimal point. However, I can't make the graph show each individual point right. I tried `domain y` and `y tick`, but it did not work.

The code is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = {Number of elements},
        ylabel = {$V[\si{\volt}]$},
        %ytick={0.0042280430,0.0042280440,0.0042280450,0.0042280460,0.0042280470}
    ]
    \addplot [
        color=black,
        mark=*
        %domain y=(0.0042280435):(0.0042280470)
]
        coordinates {
        (980,  0.0042280466)
        (1247, 0.0042280462)
        (2876, 0.0042280438)
        (4032, 0.0042280457)
        (5264, 0.0042280462)
        (5308, 0.0042280462)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is what I have:

[image: What I have]

And this is what I am seeking:

[image: What I am seeking]

My guess is latex not recognizing decimal cases after a certain point. So how do I force it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the tex arithmetic being used here simply isn't that accurate, rescale the problem multiplying the values by 10000000 and subtracting 42280 before you start

Comment: also please post complete documents not just fragments, it makes it a lot easier for people to run the code and see the issue.

Comment: the packages are \pgfplots and \siunitx

Comment: yes but why make everyone trying to help construct a document loading those. Compare with the code in the answer which can be run as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have it. There's a problem with the accuracy so you have to take smaller numbers. Hope you like it!

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
N,    V
980.,  42280466.
1247., 42280462.
2876., 42280438.
4032., 42280457.
5264., 42280462.
5308., 42280462.
}\tableNV

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\diff}{42280430.}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
height=9cm,width=12cm,
xlabel = {Number of elements},
ylabel = {$V[\si{\volt}]$},
/pgf/number format/precision=10,
/pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
/pgfplots/xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=0,1000 sep={},},
ytick={5,10,...,40},yticklabels={0.0042280435,0.0042280440,0.0042280445,0.0042280450,0.0042280455,0.0042280460,0.0042280465,0.0042280470},
xtick={930,1430,...,5430},
domain=9.3e2:5.43e3,
xmin=9.3e2,xmax=5.43e3,
ymin=5.,ymax=40.,
]
\addplot [color=black,only marks,mark=*,mark size=1pt,domain=9.3e2:5.43e3] table[y expr=\thisrow{V}-\diff] {\tableNV};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]